# Javascript FileReader working in jfiddle, but not in my browser

Tags: javascript, html

I have a file reader that works on jfiddle but wont work in any browser. Im using all the latest browsers,. It will let me select the file, but nothing happens afterwards. Im very new to javascript.

**javacript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function readFile(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = readSuccess;

    function readSuccess(evt) {
        var field = document.getElementById('main');
        field.innerHTML = evt.target.result;
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
}

document.getElementById('selectedFile').onchange = function(e) {
    readFile(e.srcElement.files[0]);
};
</script>
```

**html**

```
<input type="file" id="selectedFile" />
<div id="main"></div>
```

jfiddle

```
http://jsfiddle.net/fstreamz/ngXBV/1/
```

Comment: Hello! Could you provide a link to the jsFiddle in which this is working? jsFiddle uses your browser's engine to run script (there's nothing special about its execution model), so there must be something that jsFiddle is doing that your browser code is not doing.

Comment: jsfiddle wraps `javascript` within `onload` event, which can be viewed by inspecting source at jsfiddle. Use `window.onload = function() {//do stuff}` to call function after page resources; that is `DOM` elements. have fully loaded into `document`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) or `window.addEventListener("load")`

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
  function readFile(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = readSuccess;

    function readSuccess(evt) {
      var field = document.getElementById("main");
      field.innerHTML = evt.target.result;
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
  }

  document.getElementById("selectedFile").onchange = function(e) {
    readFile(e.srcElement.files[0]);
  };
}
</script>
Here is the html

<input type="file" id="selectedFile" accept="text/plain" />
<div id="main"></div>
```